# php curl get redirected url after get request

Tags: php, curl, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I am using the bitbucket api and there I am getting an access token when I enter the following url: '**https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/authorize?client_id={client_id}&response_type=code**' and it redirects me to **https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{my-team}/?code={code}**
And I need to get that {code} from the redirect url
I do it with curl the following way:

```
public function getCode()
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/authorize?client_id=".config('app.bitbucket_key')."&response_type=code");

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        return 'Error: invalid credentials';
    }

    return $result;
}
```

but as a result I get true. I want to get the code query parameter in the redirect url. How can I do this

**EDIT:**

When I check with `curl_getinfo()` I see that it redirects me to another url which is: https://bitbucket.org/account/signin/?next=/site/oauth2/authorize%3Fclient_id%3D{my_client_id}%26response_type%3Dcode

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about the related api but to get a html response from curl you need to set return transfer option.

```
    curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Comment: I get an empty string
but when I enter manually on that url it redirects me to the page I need